# How can I rerender the ui in tauri + vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, tauri

I'm quite new to tauri,
I tried to make an existing web-vue app a desktop app with tauri.
The problem is, that after the login, to refresh all components I run this.$router.go(),
but this does not work with tauri, does somebody know how to fix this issue or has a workaround?

```js
...
handleLogin() {
  ...
  // login process
  ...
  this.loggedIn = true;
  // refresh gui
  this.$router.go();
}
...
```

this refreshes a component like this.

```html
<p v-if="loggedIn">
  something, that should only be rendered, when logged in
</p>
```

But this only works in the browser, not with the tauri desktop app